# Handle d3 drag events only after long click

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have code to handle dragging in d3.

And I want to emit drag events only **after 1000ms**.(long click)

This is needed for mobile device for better UX.

```
var mouseover_node = null;
var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr('width', 1000).attr('height', 1000);
var rect = svg.selectAll('rect')
  .data([0, 2, 3])
  .enter().append('rect')
  .attr('x', function(x) { return +x * 0; })
  .attr('y', function(y) {  return +y * 120; })
  .attr('width', function() { return 100; })
  .attr('height', function() { return 100; })
  .attr('fill', function(x) {  if(x == 0){return'red';}else return 'blue'; });


rect.on("mouseover", (d) => {this.mouseover_node = d})
  .on("mouseout", (d) => {this.mouseover_node = null})
  .call(d3.drag()
    .on("start", function () {
        console.log('start');
        return false;
        })
    .on("drag", function () {
        console.log('drag');
        })
    .on("end",  (sourceElement,index,svgItems) => {
        console.log('end drag with mouseover: ' + this.mouseover_node);
        })
);
```

How can we do this in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

maybe use `Date.now()` in `"start"` and `"drag"` and check whether elapsed time is bigger than 1000ms.

```
var click_start, drag_start;

rect.call(
  d3.drag()
    .on("start", function () {
      console.log("start");
      click_start = Date.now();
    })
    .on("drag", function () {
      drag_start = Date.now();
      if (drag_start - click_start >= 1000) {
        console.log("drag");
      }
    })
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your Pawel, your answer would be great. And also I already used that to virtualize the long click event.
But in mobile device(as I mentioned my target is to make it working in mobile), mouse drag event to screen move is not working when I drag start from node. Here drag means finger movement. And even long click event is not working correctly in my android. and original mobile long click emits text selection instead of virtual/custom long click(1000ms).